# How to align right and vertically center in QAbstractTableModel?

Tags: python, pyside

The `Qt.AlignRight` right aligns the text but puts it into the right-top corner. The `Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter` doesn't work. Puts it into the left-top corner.

Is there a way to keep the text vertically centered and right aligned at the same time?

Code sample:

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *


class TableView(QTableView):
    def __init__(self):
        QTableView.__init__(self)
        self.setModel(TableModel(self))


class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return 1

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 2

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return 'text'

        elif role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter


app = QApplication([])
w = TableView()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

I'm using PySide 1.2.1 with Qt 4.8.6.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found that it's an old [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-20). Luckily there is a [workaround](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-20?focusedCommentId=208895&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-208895). Maybe useful for others too:

Instead of `Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter` use `int(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)`.

Comment: THANK YOU, this has always been a problem.

Comment: Bug is still present in PySide2 version 5.15.0